# Android mobile browsers, first touch on anchor tag preventing scrolling

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, browser

We have a list of `<li>` tags with the content wrapped in `<a>` tags. On page load these are the first items that are rendered, but we're experiencing an issue on android devices (chrome browser) whereby the first touch is on the  tag, so by default this performs the click action and opens the link rather than giving a chance to scroll down the page.

Has anyone else experienced this issue/found a way around? It all works fine in iOS safari.

Thanks
Ashil

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/site/123">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
            <div>
                <h5>Header</h5>
                <p>Some content</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/site/123">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
            <div>
                <h5>Header</h5>
                <p>Some content</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/site/123">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
            <div>
                <h5>Header</h5>
                <p>Some content</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: THere's more than 1 mobile browser on Android.  Saying this without specifying which one is just confusing.  The same behavior won't happen across webview, chrome, firefox, etc.  There's not even the same default preinstalled browser across all OEMs.

Comment: Sorry, experiencing this issue in chrome specifically.

Answer (score -1):

Happens to me as well on Android + Chrome. First touchstart triggers the default behaviour of the element you are on.